# Why is Jest not outputting my assertions to the terminal when it runs?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

When I run my test I see. None of the assertions I've written

[image]

What I'm expecting is something like this:

[image]

I can see the individual assertions with a tick next to them.

Comment: looks like need to add proper folder to include directory for running tests, or move your tests to test folder, that looks like default folder however, ... check up https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testregex-string

Comment: I've put them in  a __test__ folder but I still can't see any assertions

Comment: I think to answer your question, need folder structure of project, and the commands you are using to run the tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected output of jest. You just get a single success message per suite. If tests fail, then you get more detailed info about the failed tests.

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/148

This can be changed by running `jest --verbose`

Comment: Question: I noticed that the result of each assertion is not printed as they are finished, but only when the entire test is complete. Is there a way of getting the results of each assertion printed to the screen after each assertion is complete? This helps in long tests with lots of assertions. Thanks!